# Which approach should i opt for fromValue() function enum

Tags: java, performance, optimization, enums

Hi i want to provide fromValue() function in an ENUM. Could you please provide your valuable suggestion which approach should i opt for :-

1. Here we iterate ENUM values each time and return matched result.

```
    public enum DAY {
        SUNDAY("sunday"),
        MONDAY("monday"),
        TUESDAY("tuesday"),
        UNKNOWN("unknown");

        private final String value;

        DAY(final String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String value() {
            return value;
        }

        public static DAY fromValue(final String value) {
            return Stream.of(DAY.values())
                    .filter( day -> day.value().equals(value))
                    .findAny()
                    .orElse(UNKNOWN);
        }
    }
```

2. In this approach we create a Map of key value using static block and return value without iteration. But here we need to use "static block"

```
    public enum DAY {
```

```
    SUNDAY("sunday"),
    MONDAY("monday"),
    TUESDAY("tuesday"),
    UNKNOWN("unknown");

    private final String value;

    DAY(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    private static final Map<String, DAY> VALUE_TO_TYPE = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        Stream.of(DAY.values()).forEach(type -> VALUE_TO_TYPE.put(type.value, type));
    }

    public String value() {
        return value;
    }

    public static DAY fromValue(final String value) {
        final DAY day = VALUE_TO_TYPE.get(value);
        return day != null ?  day : UNKNOWN;
    }
}
```

Comment: The second seems better as more efficient while being readable. But the two implementations don't make the same thing as the parameter doesn't match. In the first one, you never return `null` but `UNKNOWN` value while in the second one, you may return `null`.

Comment: thanks @davidxxx . It's a typo. Corrected.

Comment: I prefer first approach as its  more cleaner.

Comment: I'd prefer `return DAY.valueOf(value.toUpperCase());`. Why would you even bother having `MONDAY("monday")`. That's just useless duplication. Considering that this is tagged with `performance` and `optimization`, boy are you trying to optimize in the wrong place.

Comment: BTW - you can avoid the static block altogether with `private static final Map<String, DAY> VALUE_TO_TYPE = Stream.of(DAY.values()).collect(Collectors.toMap(d -> d.value(), d -> d));`

Comment: It depends on how big your enum is. If it's just 7 elements, searching through an array will be either just as fast as using a hashset or the difference would probably be immeasurable. And option 1 seems to be ever-so-slightly easier to read. But both versions are readable enough. There's not much to choose between them. For large enums of 100000s of elements, consider option 2 but measure the performance first.

Comment: By the way, out of interest I checked Oracle's implentation Enum<T>.valueOf(). It uses your option 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going with 2nd approach with a little bit modification.

```
public enum DAY {
```

```
    SUNDAY("sunday"),
    MONDAY("monday"),
    TUESDAY("tuesday"),
    UNKNOWN("unknown");

    private final String value;

    DAY(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    private static final Map<String, DAY> VALUE_TO_TYPE = Stream.of(DAY.values()).collect(Collectors.toMap(d -> d.value, d -> d));

    public String value() {
        return value;
    }

   public static Optional<DAY> fromValue(final String value) {
       return Optional.ofNullable(VALUE_TO_TYPE.get(value));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the in-built valueOf() function -

```
public static DAY fromValue(final String value) {
    try {
        return DAY.valueOf(value.toUpperCase());
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) { 
        return UNKNOWN;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution for the enum the op posted, but it doesn't work for all enums of the same pattern, as `value` is in no way guaranteed to match the enum name... Also, `valueOf` never returns null, it throws an exception instead

Comment: Thanks for that! Updated the answer accordingly

Comment: In a real-world application, the values would not be hard-coded as "monday", "tuesday" etc. but would be read in from an internationalized properties file. One set for each language supported. So this solution wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I would just keep the code simple and implement `fromValue()` iterating over the `values()` array:

```
 public static Day fromValue(final String value) {
     for (Day day: values()) {
         if (day.value.equals(value)) {
             return day;
         }
     }
     return UNKNOWN;
  }
```

In a normal-size enum, you wouldn't likely see any noticeable difference in performance with this implementation compared to a solution that stores the values in a `static` map. If you're concerned about performance, you should first *measure* it. Only after identifying this part of the codebase a performance bottleneck should you start "optimizing" it.

The above code can be "optimized" a bit by only calling `values()` (which does an array clone under-the-hood) once and storing the array in a `static` variable:

```
private static Day[] VALUES = values();
```

Answer (score -1):

I prefer first approach as its  more cleaner.

Second approach may fail when you have same values for different keys. in that case you will have to change your map building logic. First approach will simply return the first matching key.

By Holding the  values as map does you are not  doing away with search operation as Java internally searches for the key in map

Comment: This is a small enum, so I doubt it makes much difference, but ( in general) the hash map search is faster than an iterative search...

Comment: Also, if I know what my values might repeat, I can still handle the logic in the map. In case of stream, you are never sure which value might be returned. Also, iterating over same data structure again and again for finding same value doesnt make sense to me as compared to going to a hashed location in map(definitely in terms of large enum).

Comment: I don't  see any performance improvement in Map over list when no  items are very less. Hashmap approach we are duplicating the objects and reserving the double memory space for enum values.

I have faced similar requirement tons of time and every-time I go with list approach as this looks more cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

Control flow of option 2
Output that one gets if you add the sops to constructor and static block:

conts sunday
conts monday
conts tuesday
conts unknown
static blk

So Unless you have a thing about the static block, the second option might be more performant.